# Perl GD module won't install -

Tags: perl, gd, cpan

I'm trying to figure out why I can't get the GD perl module to install on my Debian 7 server. Here is how I installed the core stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install libgd-gd2-perl
```

Then running the -MCPAN to install, I get:

```
root@myserver:~# sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install GD'
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 19 Jul 2015 21:41:02 GMT
Running install for module 'GD'
Running make for L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz

Configuring for libgd version 2.0.36.
Checking for stray libgd header files...none found.

Unknown option: installdirs
Usage: perl Build.PL [options]

Configure GD module.

 Options:
     -options       "JPEG,FT,PNG,GIF,XPM,ANIMGIF"   feature options, separated by commas
     -lib_gd_path   path            path to libgd
     -lib_ft_path   path            path to Freetype library
     -lib_png_path  path            path to libpng
     -lib_jpeg_path path            path to libjpeg
     -lib_xpm_path  path            path to libxpm
     -lib_zlib_path path            path to libpng
     -ignore_missing_gd             Ignore missing or old libgd installations and try to compile anyway

If no options are passed on the command line.  The program will
attempt to autoconfigure itself with the gdlib-config program (present
in GD versions 2.0.27 or later).  Otherwise it will prompt for these
values interactively.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site]
  LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site -- NOT OK
Running Build test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running Build install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

I've done a load of googling, but nothing seems to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed the underlying libgd package?  GD.pm is a wrapper around it.

Comment: Did `apt-get install libgd-gd2-perl` not install the Perl module? Usually package names ending in `-perl` install the associated Perl module, so I wouldn't expect you to need to use CPAN.

Comment: It's not nothing to do with a missing underlying library. The other two apparently missed the error message: **Unknown option: installdirs
Usage: perl Build.PL [options]**. `cpan` expects `Build.PL` to pass its arguments to Module::Build, but GD has a funky `Build.PL`. Answer in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Now I feel like a total pillock! For some reason, $string was empty (still gotta debug why that is, as it worked fine on the old server). As such, when it was trying to output the png image via the perl script - it was empty (so I was getting an error). Face palm!!!!

Comment: For future reference, if a module you use in your code isn't installed or perl can't find it, you'll get `Can't locate Foo/Bar.pm in @INC`; it sounds like you were getting a different error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are getting is

```
Unknown option: installdirs
Usage: perl Build.PL [options]
```

`cpan` expects `Build.PL` to pass its arguments to Module::Build, but GD has a funky `Build.PL`. Let's "fix" it.

Execute the following from a temporary directory:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz
  -or-
curl -L http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz >GD-2.56.tar.gz

tar xvzf GD-2.56.tar.gz
cd GD-2.56
perl -i~ -pE'say "Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( pass_through ));" if /GetOptions/;' Build.PL
/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site
sudo ./Build.PL installdeps
./Build.PL make
./Build.PL test
sudo ./Build.PL install
```

Comment: Thanks for the time to reply. I'm going to mark you as valid, as I recon this would have fixed my issue (I found a few posts where it was said to "fix" the Build.PL file - but never gave any info on what to do!). Either way, I think I must have got lucky as some point with something I installed - as it works now <G>

Comment: ikegami - just trying this out on a dev server (as I'm upgrading to debian 8.1), and it seems to get hung up on `perl -i~ -pE'say "Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( pass_through ));" if /GetOptions/;" Build.PL` .,.. just shows `>` on the next line, as it is waiting on more of a command?

Comment: any ideas? Stuck going live with this server, til I can get  GD going :(

Comment: The double quote is suppose to be a single quote. Fixed.

Comment: thanks @ikegami - managed to get it going by using `apt-get install libgd2-xpm-dev`, as that seems to install ok :)

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 15.04, a slight modification of the above intelligent answer seemed necessary in order to get it to install GD. This worked so that the 'cpan' program could then install GD then e.g. Image::Resize (which uses GD) afterwards. I did it after

```
sudo -i
```

in a Terminal, and after 'cd' into a temporary folder. Whether of value or not, I first did

```
apt-get install libgd-dev
```

Then this, which may contain one or more redundant lines, but it works:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/GD-2.56.tar.gz
tar xvzf GD-2.56.tar.gz
cd GD*
perl -i~ -pE'say "Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( pass_through ));" if /GetOptions/;' Build.PL
/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site
chmod 755 Build.PL
./Build.PL installdeps
./Build installdeps
./Build test
./Build install
```